# How does one find the closest element in SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I am trying to find - among all elements on an SVG drawing - the one closest in euclidean distance to a given one.

For now, I am not picky about how to measure the distance - whether between bounding boxes, centroids or anything else.

Is here a way, other than calculating the distance between every pair of elements and then sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the distance between each pair of elements, and you don't need to sort. You simply need to loop through all elements and keep track of the smallest distance/element pair:

```js
function closest( elements, toElement ){
  var closestDistance=Infinity, closestElement;
  for (var i=elements.length;i--;){
    var fromElement = elements[i];
    if (fromElement==toElement) continue;
    var distance = distanceBetween(toElement,fromElement);
    if (distance<closestDistance){
      closestElement  = fromElement;
      closestDistance = distance;
    }
  }
  return closestElement;
}
```

If you are doing this frequently **and** if you have tested the simple solution above to prove that it is too slow, then look at [space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Methods) or another method for hashing your locations for faster lookup.